# How to get the text which typing in autcomplete textview using databinding and get text in viewmodel?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-databinding

```
 layout.xml
```

> ```
>     How to get the text which typing in autcomplete textview using
>     databinding and get text in 
>     viewmodel?
> ```

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/pickup"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="8dp"
  android:background="@null"
  android:hint="@string/from"
  android:maxLength="15"
  android:onTextChanged="@{SpotViewmodel.onPasswordTextChanged}"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:singleLine="true" />
```

> ```
>   this is the viewmodel class i want to send the text which i got from 
>   autocomplete textview to api.how to implement two way binding in 
>   viewmodel class as most the examples are covered with base observables
> ```

```
SpotViewmodel.kt
```

> class SpotViewmodel :ViewModel() {
>           var data:MutableLiveData?=null
>           val first = MutableLiveData()
>           var value:String?=""
>           val apikey:String="u9fyiuc8t7"
>           var autoRepository :ServiceGenerator=ServiceGenerator().getInstance()
>           fun init() {
>           if (data != null) {
>               return
>           }
>           data = autoRepository.getStationresponse(value!!, apikey)
>           }
>          fun onPasswordTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: 
>          Int,count: 
>          Int) {
>
> ```
>     Log.e("eeeee", "" + s.toString())
>     value = s.toString()
>    }
>
>    fun getNewsRepository(): MutableLiveData<Autocompleteresponse> {
>
>     return data!!
>    }
> ```

Comment: Make two-way binding by doing   android:onTextChanged="@={SpotViewmodel.text}"

Comment: its shows error cannot find method onPasswordTextChanged in databinding

Comment: Can you show your viewmodel?

Comment: check the code now